# Declaring Persons with Constructor

Tags: c#

I have a class (People) that defines people, and contains this members:

```
    public int socialSecurityNr;
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public double heigth;
    public double weigth;
    public string Nationality;
    public int shoeSize;
```

Now, I want to create a constructor for the class that inserts the value of the social security number and sets the rest of the fields to null values. I tried this:

```
   public People(int socialSecurity, string NAME, string AGE, double HEIGTH)
        {
            socialSecurity= socialSecurityNr;
            this.name = null;
            this.age =  null;
            this.weigth = 0;
        }
```

Is this the right way to declare a constructor that should set the Social Security number and set the rest to null?

(The thing is that when I create a new Person, I should be able to give that person a name, age, height etc.)

Comment: can you give the errors?

Comment: sorry. I ment if that is the rigth way to declair a constructor that should bring in the social security number and set the rest to null

Comment: @Fredou: What errors are you referring to?

Comment: Your capitalization of member variables and function arguments is inconsistent and does not follow C# standards. Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx

Comment: This line.

    socialSecurity= socialSecurityNr;

I'm assuming you want this to be reversed?

Comment: Side note: storing a SSN as an integer won't play well if it starts with 0.

Comment: Which is it: "bring in the social security number and set the rest to null" or "When I create a new Person, I should be able to give that person a name, age, heigth etc"?

Comment: By the way, `height` and `weight` are misspelled.

Answer (score 4):

You can't declare an int as null. You can make it nullable though by doing it a nullable int like this:

```
public int? age;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just include de ss number in the constructor. By default all other reference type will be null. The errors happen because value types, like double and int can't be null.

Comment: so I dont need to put in all the other values in the constructor?

Comment: It depends of your business needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not the the entire values for instantiate a person class you can use Nullable type, with "?" at the definition.

For sample :

```
public class Person
{
    public int socialSecurityNr;
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public double heigth;

    public Person(int p_socialSecurityNr, string p_name, int? p_age, double? p_heigth)
    {
        this.socialSecurityNr = p_socialSecurityNr; // Can't be null 
        if (p_name != null)
        {
            this.name = p_name;
        }
        if (p_age != null)
        {
            this.age = p_age.Value;
        }
        if (p_heigth != null)
        {
            this.heigth = p_heigth.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than using a bunch of `if`s, why not use [`GetValueOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0.aspx)?